# Brachydios' Element?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

Brachydios' punches leave pools of slime, which eventually explode. If he hits you, he debuffs you with slime, which will explode you don't remove it by rolling or with a Cleanser. Are explosions aligned to a specific element (namely, Fire) or do they just deal raw damage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slime is actually a status effect like poison or paralysis. As a result it's only resisted with raw defense.